# java Selenium driver.quit() is ignored

Tags: java, selenium

So I'm trying to learn how to use Selenium, and I found a tutorial on the internet on how to do it (http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/first-test-case/). I know I am using internet explorer rather than firefox, but I've followed the instructions on how to setup the IEDriver. The problem is that when I use their code to simply open and close a window, it opens it, and ignores the driver.quit() that is in there.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class FirstTestCase {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String service = "C:\\Users\\abc\\Documents\\IE Explorer Server\\IEDriverServer.exe";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", service);
    InternetExplorerDriver  driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

            //Launch the Online Store Website
    driver.get("http://www.store.demoqa.com");

    // Print a Log In message to the screen
    System.out.println("Successfully opened the website www.Store.Demoqa.com");

    //Wait for 5 Sec
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    // Close the driver
    driver.quit();
    System.out.println(",");
}

}
```

It prints the comma I have set to print after it closes, but it doesn't actually close the browser. Thread.sleep() also gives an error. I've looked for over 3 hours for some kind of fix for this but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Add following line : `public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception`
It will remove Thread.sleep error

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    String service = "C:\\Users\\abc\\Documents\\IE Explorer Server\\IEDriverServer.exe";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", service);
    InternetExplorerDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

    //Launch the Online Store Website
    driver.get("http://www.store.demoqa.com");

    // Print a Log In message to the screen
    System.out.println("Successfully opened the website www.Store.Demoqa.com");

    //Wait for 5 Sec
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    // Close the driver
    driver.quit();
    System.out.println(",");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

I don't see any significant error in your code block. A few suggestions about the solution:

1. I retested your code block with Selenium 3.4.0, IEDriverServer 3.4.0 & MSIE 10.0 with only one additional parameter as

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
   ```

and  your code executes just fine. Whenever you add `Thread.sleep(5000);` in your code you may consider to add `throws InterruptedException`. But again, as per best practices we must avoid using `Thread.sleep()` and replace it by `ImplicitlyWait` or `ExplicitWait`.

2. You have used the `InternetExplorerDriver` implementation to initiate the driver. As per W3C standards you must consider using the `WebDriver` interface instead.
3. As per your comment `driver.quit()` not only closes the driver but also kills the driver instance and releases the memory.
4. Here is your own code with some small tweaks which works well at my side:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
   {
       String service = "C:\\your_directory\\IEDriverServer.exe";
       System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", service);
       WebDriver  driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
       //Launch the Online Store Website
       driver.get("http://www.store.demoqa.com");
       // Print a Log In message to the screen
       System.out.println("Successfully opened the website www.Store.Demoqa.com");
       // Quit the driver
       driver.quit();
       System.out.println(",");
   }
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question

Comment: "You have used the InternetExplorerDriver implementation to initiate the driver. As per W3C standards you must consider using the WebDriver interface instead." - I dont remember seeing any such recommendation in the W3C spec. Using an interface or an implementation is a Java specific detail and has got nothing to do with the W3C AFAIK. It would be good if you could please help clarify on this.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan Can you consider to go through my Answer again interpreting `W3C standards` as `W3C standards` only **(** not as a `recommendation` as you mentioned **)**. Let me know if you still have queries. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK W3C standards does not have any such "Standards". I would be glad if you can point me to relevant sections in the w3c spec which states that one needs to use an interface and not an implementation. That IMO is a programmer's choice

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan IMO you missed the Selenium Conference, Austin 2017 briefings. Here is the [document](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/) of WebDriver as a W3C Candidate Recommendation. Yes, programmer do have a choice but best practices always follow standards.

Comment: I am aware of the W3C spec document. What I was hoping was that you would point me to the section in the document that emphasizes on this standard. But I am not sure if using a `WebDriver` interface can be taken up as a standard here. The `WebDriver` interface is incomplete and there are a lot of other interfaces that it doesn't extend. If one is talking about standards w.r.t Selenium WebDriver, then I think one should encourage people to use `RemoteWebDriver` because all WebDriver implementations extend this (But there can always be a rogue implementation which violates this)